# autocomplete angularjs when copy text in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

im using this  [plunker autocomplete](http://plnkr.co/edit/ski53kuM5oJA21x0MO8O?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload='init()'>
  <div id='container' ng-controller='TypeaheadCtrl'>
    <h3 class="ng-binding">Item Name: {{item.name}}</h3>
    <h3 class="ng-binding">Item Id: ({{item.id}})</h3>
    <input id='itemInput' type="text" ng-model="item" placeholder="Item Name" typeahead="item as item.name for item in items | filter:$viewValue" class="form-control">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

in my project , i face problem when i try to edit i fill the input automaticly so the problem is i just get text and all the object in ng-model

for example in the link above if i copy the world Chicken and paste it in input it will not give me the object it will be just text ,
if i insert the world c and choice the option Chicken i will get in ng-model the object (that contain id and name)

Comment: I left a working plunker in my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

HERE is the working plunker **PRESS STOP THEN RUN, BUG IN PLUNKER** : http://plnkr.co/edit/QGqDjhzcFVNSHxA2hmHM?p=preview

It should be `ng-bind` not `ng-binding` and it shouldn't be `class = ng-binding` (angular directives are not css classes) it should be `Item name: <h3 ng-bind="item.name"></h3>`.  Here's an example from the angularJS website:

```
<script>
  angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.name = 'Whirled';
}]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></label><br>
  Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span>!
</div>
```

and here's your code edited:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"     href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/angular.min.js">    </script>
  <script     src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload='init()'>
  <div id='container' ng-controller='TypeaheadCtrl'>
Item name: <h3 ng-bind="item.name"></h3>
Item ID: <h3 ng-bind="item.id"></h3>
<input id='itemInput' type="text" ng-model="item" placeholder="Item Name" typeahead="item as item.name for item in items | filter:$viewValue" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at working example,

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z930HmH83KIENuEjWhx3?p=preview

I have change your code a bit and made it angular code rather than java script code.

I hope it will work. I have taken your json in .json file and using $http service made call to that json.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.factory('autoComplete',function($http){
  return{
    load:function(){
      $http.get('data.json').success(function (data){

            sessionStorage.setItem( 'items', JSON.stringify(data) );
      })
  }
  }
})

app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl',function($scope,$http,autoComplete){
        $scope.selected = undefined;
        $scope.items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('items'));
});
```

I hope that little modification to this solution would take you to your required solution.